# Symfony2 Docrtine - Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key - It does have a primary key?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Having a strange issue with SF2 and Doctrine. When trying to run my app from app.php I get this:

```
[2013-01-31 15:40:05] request.CRITICAL: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: No identifier/primary key specified for Entity 'ACME\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity'. Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key. (uncaught exception) at /lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php line 37 [] []
```

Which seems fairly self explanatory. But as far as I can see , I have a Primary key on my entity:

My Entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="milestone")
*/
class MyEntity
{

   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * @Assert\MinLength(2)
    * @Assert\MaxLength(100)
    */
    protected $title;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    */
    protected $date;
   //////ETC
```

And then in PHPMyAdmin:

```
        Action          Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
 Edit    Drop   PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  63  A
```

I have the primary key. Non are NULL.

Running using app_dev.php the app runs fine, I'm assuming as the error is suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

try using this. It is working for me

```
/**
     * @var integer $id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the field to be not nullable.

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $id;
```

In any case since you have the table, you can always generate your entity map using doctrine's cli which is very convenient.

```
php [path-to-doctrine]/doctrine orm:convert-mapping --filter="TableNameInCamelCase"  --namespace="[your-entity-namespace]" --force --from-database annotation [destination-path-of-entities]
```

There's even one for generating the getters and setters.